# Python dataframe split a string column into many

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe

The data I import comes in irregular fashion.

```
df = 
# following data all in one column
1 CABATT   CAR BATTERY VOLTAGE  -10.0 200.0
2 CPTEMP   CAR DAS PANEL TEMP C -10.0  200.0
3 CAPTMA   CAR PANEL A TEMP C  -10.0   200.0

205 SPPT4P   SPEED INPUT 4 CYCLINDER  0.0  32000.0

# Slicing the first three digital numbers as SNO

print(df[df.columns[0]].str.extract('(?P<SNO>\S\d{3}\S)'))

0   NaN
1   NaN
2   NaN
3   NaN
4   NaN
```

Expected output:

```
SNo ABBRE    DESCRIPTION                                                     MIN        MAX
1 CABATT   CAR BATTERY VOLTAGE                                              -10.0      200.0
2 CPTEMP   CAR DAS PANEL TEMP C                                             -10.0      200.0
3 CAPTMA   CAR PANEL A TEMP C                                                -10.0      200.0

205 SPPT4P   SPEED INPUT 4 CYCLINDER                                              0.0    32000.0
```

Comment: Your code example is a bit confusing, since it contains both Python code and (what I assume to be) console output. Could you modify your code example such that it contains only runnable code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract your data:

```
^(?P<SNo>\d+)\s+(?P<ABBRE>\w+)\s+(?P<DESCRIPTION>.*?)\s+(?P<MIN>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<MAX>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$
```

It matches:

- `^` : start of string
- `(?P<SNo>\d+)` : some number of digits, captured in group `SNo`
- `(?P<ABBRE>\w+)` : some number of word characters, captured in group `ABBREV`
- `(?P<DESCRIPTION>.*?) : a minimal number of characters, captured in group` DESCRIPTION`
- `(?P<MIN>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` : a possibly negative integer or floating point number, captured in group `MIN`
- `(?P<MAX>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` : a possibly negative integer or floating point number, captured in group `MAX`
- `$` : end of string

Each capture group is separated by some number of spaces `\s+`

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/91y2Rf/1)

In python:

```py
out = df[df.columns[0]].str.extract(r'^(?P<SNo>\d+)\s+(?P<ABBRE>\w+)\s+(?P<DESCRIPTION>.*?)\s+(?P<MIN>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+(?P<MAX>-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$')
```

Output:

```
   SNo   ABBRE              DESCRIPTION    MIN      MAX
0    1  CABATT      CAR BATTERY VOLTAGE  -10.0    200.0
1    2  CPTEMP     CAR DAS PANEL TEMP C  -10.0    200.0
2    3  CAPTMA       CAR PANEL A TEMP C  -10.0    200.0
3  205  SPPT4P  SPEED INPUT 4 CYCLINDER    0.0  32000.0
```